# Python: Creating a 2D histogram from a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matplotlib, histogram

I'm new to python.

I have a numpy matrix, of dimensions 42x42, with values in the range 0-996. I want to create a 2D histogram using this data. I've been looking at tutorials, but they all seem to show how to create 2D histograms from random data and not a numpy matrix.

So far, I have imported:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
```

I'm not sure if these are correct imports, I'm just trying to pick up what I can from tutorials I see.

I have the numpy matrix `M` with all of the values in it (as described above). In the end, i want it to look something like this:

[image: 2D histogram]

obviously, my data will be different, so my plot should look different. Can anyone give me a hand?

**Edit:** For my purposes, **Hooked**'s example below, using matshow, is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: what is your x and y in numpy matrix, its basically 42 rows and 42 columns. what is your x, y values?

Comment: Yes, my matrix is 42 rows and 42 columns. In each index, there is an integer from 0-996 that was computed and placed there earlier in the program.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have the raw data from the counts, you could use `plt.hexbin` to create the plots for you (IMHO this is better than a square lattice): Adapted from the example of [`hexbin`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)
plt.hexbin(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you already have the Z-values in a matrix as you mention, just use `plt.imshow` or `plt.matshow`:

```
XB = np.linspace(-1,1,20)
YB = np.linspace(-1,1,20)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(XB,YB)
Z = np.exp(-(X**2+Y**2))
plt.imshow(Z,interpolation='none')
```

[image]

Comment: To get the axes labeled correctly, you can pass extent to imshow with the min and max values of the bin edges.

Comment: Check also the [official examples](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) using the *matplotlib* functions `imshow`, `pcolormesh` and `NonUniformImage`.

Answer (score 15):

If you have not only the 2D histogram matrix but also the underlying `(x, y)` data, then you could make a scatter plot of the `(x, y)` points and color each point according to its binned count value in the 2D-histogram matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)
xedges, yedges = np.linspace(-4, 4, 42), np.linspace(-25, 25, 42)
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, (xedges, yedges))
xidx = np.clip(np.digitize(x, xedges), 0, hist.shape[0]-1)
yidx = np.clip(np.digitize(y, yedges), 0, hist.shape[1]-1)
c = hist[xidx, yidx]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)

plt.show()
```

---

[image: Example scatter plot of 2D histogram]

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of the 'scatter histogram', but I don't think the other solutions fully do them justice. [Here is a module](https://gist.github.com/lkilcher/8722204056c117bc1ff0edc5b4b4a29e) that implements them. The major advantage of the `scatter_hist2d` function compared to the other solutions is that it sorts the points by the hist data (see the `mode` argument). This means that the result looks more like a traditional histogram (i.e., you don't get the chaotic overlap of markers in different bins).

[image: The scatter-histogram]

MCVE for this figure (using [the hist_scatter module](https://gist.github.com/lkilcher/8722204056c117bc1ff0edc5b4b4a29e)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from hist_scatter import scatter_hist2d

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5, 4])
ax = plt.gca()

x = randgen.randn(npoint)
y = 2 + 3 * x + 4 * randgen.randn(npoint)

scat = scatter_hist2d(x, y,
                      bins=[np.linspace(-4, 4, 42),
                            np.linspace(-25, 25, 42)],
                      s=5,
                      cmap=plt.get_cmap('viridis'))
ax.axhline(0, color='k', linestyle='--', zorder=3, linewidth=0.5)
ax.axvline(0, color='k', linestyle='--', zorder=3, linewidth=0.5)
plt.colorbar(scat)
```

---

## Room for improvement?

The primary drawback of this approach is that the points in the densest areas overlap the points in lower density areas, leading to somewhat of a misrepresentation of the areas of each bin. I spent quite a bit of time exploring two approaches for resolving this:

1. using smaller markers for higher density bins
2. applying a 'clipping' mask to each bin

The first one [gives results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drSaw.png) that are way too crazy. The second one looks nice -- especially if you only clip bins that have >~20 points -- but it is *extremely slow* ([this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kOl2.png) took about a minute).

**So, ultimately I've decided** that by carefully selecting the marker size and bin size (`s` and `bins`), you can get results that are visually pleasing and not too bad in terms of misrepresenting the data. After all, these 2D histograms are usually intended to be visual aids to the underlying data, not strictly quantitative representations of it. Therefore, I think this approach is far superior to 'traditional 2D histograms' (e.g., `plt.hist2d` or `plt.hexbin`), and I presume that if you've found this page you're also not a fan of traditional (single color) scatter plots.

*If I were king of science, I'd make sure all 2D histograms did something like this for the rest of forever.*

## UPDATE

I added a `scatter_hexbin` function to [the module](https://gist.github.com/lkilcher/8722204056c117bc1ff0edc5b4b4a29e).

[image: Comparison of different 2-D histogram types.]

Answer (score 1):

[@unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27156971/2173516) contains a mistake: `xidx` and `yidx` are calculated the wrong way (at least on my data sample). The correct way should be:

```
xidx = np.clip(np.digitize(x, xedges) - 1, 0, hist.shape[0] - 1)
yidx = np.clip(np.digitize(y, yedges) - 1, 0, hist.shape[1] - 1)
```

As the return dimension of `np.digitize` that we are interested in is between `1` and `len(xedges) - 1`, but the `c = hist[xidx, yidx]` needs indices between `0` and `hist.shape - 1`.

---

Below is the comparison of results. As you can see you get similar but not the same result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

n = 10000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)
xedges, yedges = np.linspace(-4, 4, 42), np.linspace(-25, 25, 42)
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, (xedges, yedges))

xidx = np.clip(np.digitize(x, xedges), 0, hist.shape[0] - 1)
yidx = np.clip(np.digitize(y, yedges), 0, hist.shape[1] - 1)
c = hist[xidx, yidx]
old = ax1.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='jet')

xidx = np.clip(np.digitize(x, xedges) - 1, 0, hist.shape[0] - 1)
yidx = np.clip(np.digitize(y, yedges) - 1, 0, hist.shape[1] - 1)

c = hist[xidx, yidx]
new = ax2.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='jet')


plt.show()
```

[image: Same Same but Different]

Comment: When posting an answer make sure your answer doesn't rely on information given in other answers. You correctly described the problem in another answer (which is a good thing to do) but then **only provided a partial solution** that cannot be used whithout looking at the other answer. Please **edit** your answer and include a complete snippet or your post will probably be deleted.