# How to modify inf into an index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, indexing, nan

I am very new to the Python business, therefore I ask to the community for some extra support. I have a pandas DataFrame that has `.index` and `.column` in the form of IntervalIndex. As you can see from the following output, the first `.left` element and the last `.right` element of the tuple(?) are `inf`:

```
IntervalIndex([[-inf, -1.0), [-1.0, -0.9), [-0.9, -0.8), [-0.8, -0.7), [-0.7, -0.6) ... [0.6000000000000001, 0.7000000000000002), [0.7000000000000002, 0.8), [0.8, 0.9000000000000001), [0.9000000000000001, 1.0), [1.0, inf)],
              closed='left',
              name='cos(theta)',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

I am trying to plot a 2D histo with `plt.pcolormesh(x,y,C)` , which complains because:

```
ValueError: x and y arguments to pcolormesh cannot have non-finite values or be of type numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray with masked values
```

I need `pcolormesh` because my data consists of a C matrix of values (counts), an x index (cos(theta)) and a y column (energy). The dimensions of C should match the length of x and y, therefore I can't simply slice the edges with something like `pivot_pipanda.index.left[1:]` for -inf.

I want to replace `-inf` with the value of the `.right` value of its tuple (i.e. `[-inf, -1.0)` ) - the centre value of the bin after (all bins have the same width) and the specular for `inf`. I have thought about naive approaches like `.apply()` or `.raplace()`, but they aren't available methods for .`index.left` or `.index.right` . I can get a mask of booleans with the syntax `pivot_df.index.left.isin(["-inf"])`

```
 array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False])
```

but I can't imagine a function that does the job.

Any idea is very welcome!

Comment: A possible workaround is to covert the histogram into a my"Dhisto.numpy() . Nevertheless, th conversion excludes -inf and +inf ending up with the lenght of both .index and .column 1 item less that the .shape of the z counts.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is as suggested by Jim `my2Dhisto.numpy()` .

For more details [please have a look here](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot4/issues/100#issuecomment-692224133)