# Create density plot from 2d matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, imshow

I have a 2d matrix of values which I would like to plot as a 2d histogram.

A simplified example:
I have a 1d array of initial velocities, say `vi = [1, 2, 3]`, and for each value in `vi`, I have a row of corresponding final velocities stored in a 2d array, `vf = [ [0.7, 1.1, 1.5], [1.8, 2.1, 2.4], [2.7, 2.9, 3.1] ]`.
I want to be able to make a 2d histogram of the points `(vi, vf)`, i.e., the coordinates `[1, 0.7], [1, 1.1], [1, 1.5], [2, 1.8], [2, 2.1], [2, 2.4], and [3,2.7], [3, 2.9], [3, 3.1]`.

Is there a way to create such parings?

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156381/python-creating-a-2d-histogram-from-a-numpy-matrix) advises to use imshow or matshow, but that colors bins by the value assigned to each element. What I need is a plotting routine that takes a 2d matrix, divides it into a grid, and colors each bin by the *count* in each bin.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should at least add an example of your data and explain how you want them in 2d bins. Where do the values stand for?

Comment: added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a 2D space, where the x-values come from `vi` and the y-values from `vf`.  Repeating `vi` `n` times (with `n` the row-length of `vf`) makes the `x` and `y` arrays have the same number of elements, corresponding to the desired tuples.

In code:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

vi = np.array([1, 2, 3])
vf = np.array([[0.7, 1.1, 1.5], [1.8, 2.1, 2.4], [2.7, 2.9, 3.1]])

x = np.repeat(vi, vf.shape[1]) # repeat the x-values by the row-length of `vf`
y = vf.ravel() # convert to a 1D array
sns.histplot(x=x, y=y)
plt.show()
```

With so little data, the plot looks quite uninteresting. You'll have to test with the real data to find out whether it is what you're expecting.

`print([*zip(x,y)])` prints `(x,y)` as tuples, i.e.

```py
[(1, 0.7), (1, 1.1), (1, 1.5), (2, 1.8), (2, 2.1), (2, 2.4), (3, 2.7), (3, 2.9), (3, 3.1)]
```